# How do I simulate a usb thumbdrive insertion in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, simulation

I am writing code that tests a black-box application's behavior. Part of what I need to test is how the application reacts to a USB thumbdrive insertion. The application receives notification of a USB insertion via a udev rule.

I would like the ability to simulate a USB insertion event so that the event trickles up through udev in order to write an automated test suite. Preferably, I would like to somehow point to a filesystem-in-a-file for it to mount and treat as the thumbdrive.

Does anyone know how to do this in Linux? Thanks.